# email from is displaying same as MAIL_USERNAME not as define in from() function laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, phpmailer

i'm using `smtp.gmail.com` in my `.env` files and trying to create contact_us form in view, and everything working fine until i saw the sender.

the sender is not supposed to same as `->to()` function, it should be whatever the user input in `$data['email']`

i see some tutorial using mailtrap and the code below working fine, but if i'm using gmail, everything working fine except the `sender email` or the `$message->to()` is not displaying

```
Mail::send('email.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){

   $message->from($data['email']); // e.g user_email@mail.com
   $message->to(env('MAIL_USERNAME')); // my email : myemail@gmail.com
   $message->subject($data['subject']);

});
```

help pls, thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

Try below given code. Before use below code, make sure that value for variable '`MAIL_USERNAME`' is properly set into `.env`

```
$data['to_email'] = env('MAIL_USERNAME');
Mail::send('email.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){

   $message->from($data['email']); // e.g user_email@mail.com
   $message->to($data['to_email']); // my email : myemail@gmail.com
   $message->subject($data['subject']);

});
```